# Две кнопки в форме, выполняющие разные вещи

Tags: php, javascript, html

Допустим, у меня есть некая форма обратной связи. Я хочу, чтобы в ней было две кнопки. Первая выполняет некий скрипт, а вторая уже отправляла форму. Как это реализовать?  Меня интересует именно реализация кнопок.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form action="serverSide.php" method="post">
```

Одна кнопка:

```
  <button type="button" onclick="nekijScript()">Odna Knopka</button>
```

а вторая:

```
  <button type="submit">Vtoraja Knopka</button>

</form>

<script>
function nekijScript() {
  alert("I am some script.");
}
</script>
```